# "A little this and that"

Tags: phrases, adjectives

When ordering a sandwich today, I said, "Could you give me a little lettuce and onions?" because I wanted small amounts of lettuce and onions. However, when I thought about it later, I wasn't sure if the use of "a little" applied to just the lettuce or both the lettuce and the onions. When you say you want "a little (1) and (2)," does that mean you want a small amount of (1) and a normal amount of (2), or small amounts of both?

Comment: It doesn't matter -- the sandwich droids will put on the standard amount regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you put the comma, or pause, in your speech pattern:

> Could you give me a little lettuce, and onions?

Or

> Could you give me a little lettuce and onions?

That said, some people have difficulty picking up the intotations (and therefore the meaning) of other peoples' speech, so to be overly clear, I'd simply specify something like this:

> Lettuce and onions; a little of both, please.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said, "easy on both the lettuce and onions."

Or to use your wording, "Can you give me a little of both lettuce and onions."

It's the use of the word "both" that denotes you mean to include the two of them together in the same context.

Alternatively, you could use the word "little" in front of each:
"Can you give me a little lettuce and a little onions?"

Such that there's no confusion due to intonation.